# Color rows by a factor column in dataframe - R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with many column that one of them is a factor type called "c_code"
It has 100 levels and each level contains about 10-15 values (rows).
how do I color rows by the levels so thats each following level has a different color?
I'm adding a picture of what I want:
[image]

as you can see, each C_code value had a different color (=each level at the factor column)

At the end I want to export the file as .csv

thanks a lot,
Ido

Comment: Where do you want the color to show up? In your console? In a `View()` window? Saving the table as an image? Embedding the table in a `knitr` document? (What PDF, HTML, Word, or something else?) Writing to a spreadsheet? (Excel or Google Sheets or something else?) Somewhere else?

Comment: thank you for you answer. I forgot to say that I'm exporting the data using "write.csv" and opening it with excel.

Comment: So you're saying you want the rows color coded in the excel spreadsheet? Any reason why you wouldn't do that inside excel?

Comment: I'm about to work with a mega size file, about 3K of rows. I'd like to find a solution if possible without doing is manualy

Comment: CSV files are simple, just Comma Separated Values - they have no formatting. If you want to embed formatting for Excel you'll need to produce a .xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to try.

First, create a group number based on `C_CODE`, so that each group will be highlighted the same.

With `openxlsx` you can use `conditionalFormatting` to highlight, based on whether this group number is even or odd. This will be based on styles created with `createStyle`.

I created an example data frame `df` for testing here. This assumes you want alternating colors between 2 colors, as opposed to having a unique color for each group with 100 colors.

```
library(openxlsx)

df <- data.frame(
  C_Code = c("AA12", "AA12", "BB34", "BB34", "TT789", "TT789", "TT789"),
  Type = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,3),
  Session = c(rep(1:2, times = 3), 3),
  Score = sample(100, 7)
)

# When C_Code changes, assign a new group number
df$Group <- cumsum(c(TRUE, head(df$C_Code, -1) != tail(df$C_Code, -1)))

# Create styles with color, fill, etc.
negStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#9C0006", bgFill = "#FFC7CE")
posStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#006100", bgFill = "#C6EFCE")

# Make the workbook
wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, "example")

writeData(wb, "example", df)

# Add the formatting
conditionalFormatting(wb, "example", cols = 1:4, rows = 1:nrow(df), rule = "ISODD($E1)", style = negStyle)
conditionalFormatting(wb, "example", cols = 1:4, rows = 1:nrow(df), rule = "ISEVEN($E1)", style = posStyle)

saveWorkbook(wb, "myExample.xlsx", TRUE)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understand the logic and indeed a column was added and it is possible to set a defferent color for the odd and even. I couldn't understand where the colors are created, even when running your code and exporting the file you created I couldn't see any color changes at the csv file I exported.

Comment: Thanks. I thought since you were planning to load the csv file into Excel this might meet your needs. Does this solution work for you (exporting to Excel directly instead of a csv file)? The colors are embedded in the styles created but are specific for Excel. If you save as a csv file there won't be any formatting. Let me know if I can clarify further, or feel free to describe more about what you need.